# How to get the specific information from an element in JSOUP?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to parse an html file using jsoup. Here is my code:

```
Document doc;
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.marketimyilmazlar.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=64_80&product_id=14102").get();

Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("price");
```

Then, when i look at the elements variable, its content is like the following:

```
<div class="price">
   2.75 TL
  <span class="kdv">KDV Dahil</span> 
  <br /> 
</div>7
```

Here, what i want to do is that, I want to get the value "2.75TL". I thought of using elements.get(int index) method, but do not know how to use index variable. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ownText method, e.g.

```
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("price");
System.out.println(elements.get(0).ownText()); // 2.75 TL
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple, you need to get the text nodes out of the element, and then take the first of it, so the solution is something like:

```
element.textNodes().get(0);
```